# Entity framework 6 dynamic connections string using DI

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, connection-string, unit-of-work, .net-4.6

I have a unit of work with the repository pattern with simple injector implemented and I need to change my connection string dynamically. Currently the connection string is taken from the web config. I need the connection string be taken from the database.

So I will have a database with the ASP.Net Identity and the connections strings (and other configurations needed for my application) and then a database depending on the client.

My repositories and Unit of work are as follows.

```cs
public abstract class DataRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IDataRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IObjectStateEntity, new()
    where TContext : class, IDbSimpleContextAsync
    {
        protected DataRepositoryBase(TContext context)
        {
            Context = context;            
        }

        public virtual TContext Context { get; }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
        {
            return Context.Get<TEntity>();
        }

        public TEntity Get(object id)
        {
            return Context.Find<TEntity>(id);
        }
}

public class SomeRepository : DataRepositoryBase<SomeObject, IContext>, ISomeRepository
{
    public SomeRepository (IContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class UnitOfWorkBase : IUnitOfWork
{
    private IDbSimpleContextAsync _dbContext;

    protected UnitOfWorkBase(IDbSimpleContextAsync dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public class UnitOfWork : UnitOfWorkBase, IUnitOfWork
{
    private ISomeRepository _someRepository
    private readonly IContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(IContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public ISomeRepository SomeRepository => _someRepository ?? (_someRepository = new SomeRepository(_dbContext));
}

public class BookingBusiness : IBookingBusiness
{
    protected IAllotmentUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }

    public AllotmentBusinessBase(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    ...
    business methods here
    ...
}
```

So my idea is when reaching business, I query the configuration database for the connection string for the current user (the current unit of work injected points to that database), and somehow use that connection to instantiate a new unit of work for to connect to the correct database. Any ideas how i can achieve this using my current setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prevent injecting objects into the object graph that change based on runtime information. The question here is whether or not the connection string is still a constant value (won't change after the application started), or can change from request to request (for instance, when each user gets its own connection string).

In case the connection string is a constant, the solution is simple: Just request the connection string at start-up and use it indefinitely, just as you already are doing currently.

If your connection string isn't a constant value from the config file, but runtime information, it and its consuming `DbContext` should not be injected anymore directly into the object graph. Instead, you should define an abstraction that allows requesting the correct `DbContext` based on runtime information, such as logged in user.

So instead of injecting an `IContext` into `SomeRepository` and `UnitOfWork`, inject an `IContextProvider`, which can be defined as follows:

```cs
public interface IContextProvider
{
    IContext Context { get; }
}
```

Your `DataRepositoryBase` can use `IContextProvider` as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
{
    return this.contextProvider.Context.Get<TEntity>();
}

public TEntity Get(object id)
{
    return this.contextProvider.Context.Find<TEntity>(id);
}
```

The part left is to define an implementation for `IContextProvider` that can load the right connection string from the database, and create and cache a `DbContext` based on that connection string. Considering the limited amount of information given, this is only something you will know how to do.

Comment: Thank you Steven for your response. The application is using angular 5 for the UI and web api 2 as the backend.  I have 2 types of connection strings every request; one that is constant and always points to the configuration database and one that can change every time. The connection string that can change is queried from the configuration database.

Comment: But if IContextProvider creates the DBContext, dont I have the same problem? I need to get the connection string from 1 database, create a new context for the returned connection string.

Comment: You won't have the same problem, because you should create the DbContext lazily, _after_ your object graph is resolved. The DbContext should be created on the first call to `IContextProvider.Context`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! this has put me on the right track!

Comment: One final question. I'm assuming the IContextProvider will have some method that accepts the connection string and creates a context. Should I use the container to create the context instead of new?